# GetModuleFileName different behavior on Win 7/Win 10

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm using libeay32.dll/ssleay32.dll library in my application for https support. Library is successfully loaded on Windows 7 (not by my application, by Qt library), however I'm getting SSL error on Windows 10.

I wrote a small application to ensure whether correct instance of library is loaded (not from PATH for example) and got interesting result.

Here's the code

```
HMODULE hSsleay = LoadLibrary("ssleay32.dll");
DWORD pathSize = GetModuleFileName(hSsleay, ssleayPath, pathSize);
if (pathSize) {
    std::cout << "Module ssleay32.dll detected path = " << ssleayPath << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "Module ssleay32.dll detection error LastError = " << GetLastError() << '\n';
}
```

Output on Windows 7 x86 is

> Module ssleay32.dll detected path = C:/Program Files/My Application/ssleay32.dll

However, on Windows 10 x64 it is

> Module ssleay32.dll detected path = C:/Program Files (x86)/My Application/LibraryLocator.exe

Where LibraryLocator.exe is a name of a testing application, containing the code above

Comment: Error checking is crucial, don't let a NULL return value from LoadLibrary() go unnoticed.

Comment: If `LoadLibrary` fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why. This is explained in the documentation. I urge you to get in to the habit of reading it.

Comment: You must call GetLastError() *immediately* after you detect failure.  Don't call any function in between, not even a library function, it can screw up the error value.  LoadLibrary error codes are documented everywhere.

Comment: GetLastError returns 126 (The specified module could not be found), even though the library is the same directory as an application

Comment: That error means that the module you load, or one of its dependencies can't be found. If the module is in the same directory as the executable, it stands to reason that its a dependency that cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks. I think will try DependencyWalker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetModuleFileName()` returns the path of the calling process when its `hModule` parameter is set to NULL. `LoadLibrary()` returns NULL on failure. So clearly, your call to `LoadLibrary()` is failing (for instance, if your 32bit EXE tries to load the 64bit version of the DLL, or it can't find the DLL on the `PATH` since you are not specifying an absolute path). You are not handling the error before calling `GetModuleFileName()`.

If Qt has already loaded the DLL for you, you should be using `GetModuleHandle()` instead of `LoadLibrary()`.

Comment: > "If Qt has already loaded the DLL for you, you should be using GetModuleHandle() instead of LoadLibrary()" it's a separate console app, though thanks, will try

Comment: What is the point of writing a separate test app? If you don't know how the Qt app is loading the DLL, you can't reliably test it in a separate app. The Qt app could be loading the DLL by absolute path, or it could be relying on the system `PATH`, or a combination via `SetDllDirectory()`/`AddDllDirectory()`, or the Registry `Known DLLs` key. Many different ways for `LoadLibrary()` to find a DLL. But in any case, you must use `GetLastError()` to find out WHY `LoadLibrary()` is failing. If bitness is not the reason, the most likely reason is the DLL (or one of its dependencies) is not found

Comment: GetLastError returns 126 (The specified module could not be found). Yeah, Qt calls LoadLibrary

Comment: @YuriS.Cherkasov like I said, the DLL (or one of its dependencies) is not being found. Try using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see exactly which DLL is failing to be found and where it is being searched at. And Qt may be using `LoadLibrary()` but you don't how HOW it is being used, unless you have the source code..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `LoadLibrary` call fails and returns a `NULL` since you never check returned value and pass it directly to `GetModuleFileName` you obtain the path to the calling executable. Anothing thing is that you need to use wide versions of those functions, e.g. `LoadLibraryW`, otherwise it may fail on some systems.